# Transfer of an EM wave's momentum according to Lorentz Force

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, momentum

Momentum density in electromagnetism is

\begin{equation}
\vec{p_{EM}}=\frac{\vec{E} \times \vec{B}}{4\pi c}
\end{equation}

so, when dealing with electromagnetic waves, momentum seems to be transfered in the direction of propagation of the wave, let's say $\hat{z}$. From this I asume that if I put a charge $q$ in front of the wave, it will give the charge momentum in $\hat{z}$. However, looking at $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{B}$ and using the Lorentz Force, it seems that the charge should receive momentum not only in $\hat{z}$. How is this explained? I'm guessing that maybe if the charge gets momentum in another direction is because the wave got deflected in the opposite one, but I'm not sure.

(I'd like an explanation that doesn't include photons, since this should work just using classical mechanics and the Lorentz Force)

Comment: To do this fully self-consistently, you have to consider also the electric and magnetic fields produced by the charge and its motion, and the momentum carried of by *radiation* produced by the wiggling of the charge. It is worked out in detail in Rohrlich, *Classical Charged Particles*.